# "он или она сделает" vs "он или она сделают"

Tags: словоупотребление

Which one is correct, or are they both? Is there a difference in meaning between them?

Answer (score 4):

1. "или" means "or"
2. "сделает" is a singular form of verb "сделать"
3. "сделают" is a plural verb of verb "сделать"

In English:

> He or she will make <...>

means that a single person out of two will make it, therefore, it needs a singular verb:

> Он или она сделает <...>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could "он или она" express "inclusive or"?

Comment: @user5455 It does not much depend on inclusiveness or exclusiveness. The general recommendation for **или** given in grammar guides (those focusing on difficult cases) is to use plural if your *sentence is in the Past tense, and subjects have different genders*. If subjects are the same gender OR there is no need to show  gender (eg., Present tense),use singular.

Comment: I think, such sentences sometimes use plural in speech, too. So it is a "mild" mistake if you get it wrong. I would probably use "Кто-нибудь из них сделает..." anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Much depends on context.

1. Typically, in cases without an emphasis on 'who of them' (he, she or both) "сделают" is suitable.

Они это сделают - он или она. (They will do it - either he or she. )

Он или она сделают это. (Be it he or she - they will do it. )

2. If definied 'just one of them will do it', then more likely "сделает" is the choice:

Не так важно, он или она это сделает. (It's not so important, who of them will do it)

Кто-то из них - он или она - сделает это. (similar meaning: one of them, either he or she)

Comment: Гениальный ответ. Очень много плюсов.